# Dynamic methods/values available on empty path?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

Is it possible to **set up a `Dynamic` subtype so that dynamic vals/defs can be invoked from the empty path, and, if yes, how?**

Illustration:

```
import scala.language.dynamics
class Blah extends Dynamic { 
    def selectDynamic(name: String) = println(name)
}

new Blah {selectDynamic("foo")} //compiles
new Blah {this.foo} //also compiles

new Blah {foo} //error: not found: value foo
```

Comment: I don't really understand the deeper meaning behind that piece of code. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @StefanKunze : the goal is to have the third anon class declaration behave like the first one. The reason for asking is playing around with DSL definitions - the problem's more general than that, of course.